# Como escolher o o melhor em cada ano de uma coluna no R?

Tags: r

Tenho uma tabela com a eficiencia de cada jogador, o ano da temporada e o nome do jogador. Como posso fazer com que me dê uma tabela final com o melhor jogador (maior eficiencia) de cada ano? Me dando o nome do jogador e sua eficiencia e ano em uma tabela

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando o pacote `dplyr` ou `data.table` é possível fazer isto.

- Criando dados:

```
# dados ficticios
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(ano = rep(2015:2018, each = 5),
                 nome = rep(letters[1:4], 5),
                 eficiencia = rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0.6, sd = 0.1))
df
```

```
> df
    ano nome eficiencia
1  2015    a  0.5373546
2  2015    b  0.6183643
3  2015    c  0.5164371
. . .
18 2018    b  0.6943836
19 2018    c  0.6821221
20 2018    d  0.6593901
```

---

- Aplicando o pacote `dplyr` com `top_n`:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(ano) %>% # agrupar por ano
  dplyr::top_n(1)          # apenas o melhor (1) em cada ano
df2
```

```
> df2
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ano [4]
    ano nome  eficiencia
  <int> <fct>      <dbl>
1  2015 d          0.760
2  2016 d          0.674
3  2017 c          0.751
4  2018 b          0.694
```

Ou com `slice`:

```
df3 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(ano) %>% 
  dplyr::slice(which.max(eficiencia))
df3
```

```
> df3
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ano [4]
    ano nome  eficiencia
  <int> <fct>      <dbl>
1  2015 d          0.760
2  2016 d          0.674
3  2017 c          0.751
4  2018 b          0.694
```

---

- Aplicando o pacote `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dft <- data.table::data.table(df)

df4 <- dft[dft[, .I[eficiencia == max(eficiencia)], by = ano]$V1]
df4
```

```
> df4
    ano nome eficiencia
1: 2015    d  0.7595281
2: 2016    d  0.6738325
3: 2017    c  0.7511781
4: 2018    b  0.6943836
```

Ou com:

```
df5 <- data.table::setDT(dft)[, .SD[which.max(eficiencia)], by = ano]
df5
```

```
> df5
    ano nome eficiencia
1: 2015    d  0.7595281
2: 2016    d  0.6738325
3: 2017    c  0.7511781
4: 2018    b  0.6943836
```